# Not able to perform network calls unit testing in KMM (Kotlin multiplatform mobile)

Tags: android, ios, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm writing my logical part in shared folder. Am using KTOR library to fetch the data from server. Here is my code to fetch the data from server:

```
fun testApi(
    success: () -> Unit,
    failure: (Error) -> Unit) {

    val manager = getAuthorizationHTTPManager("jsonplaceholder.typicode.com", false)
    if (manager == null) {
        val error = BLError.error(BLErrorCodes.consumerCloudPostOAuthFailed,  "Unable to create a session manager")
        BLLog.logError(error)
        failure(error)
        return
    }
    // Perform the request
    val viewScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
    viewScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO)  {
        try {
            val response = manager.get("/posts")

            Napier.d(response.body<String>().toString())
            if(response.status.value in 200 .. 299){
                success()
            }
            else {
                val json = JsonObject(response.body())
                val error = BLError.error(BLErrorCodes.consumerCloudPostOAuthFailed, json["error"].toString())
                failure(error)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            val error = BLError.error(BLErrorCodes.consumerCloudPostOAuthFailed, e.toString())
            failure(error)
        }
    }
}
```

As we can check testApi method return success & error callback as per the response. **getAuthorizationHTTPManager** method is used to create the httpClient. get() & post() both are suspend functions. That's why am using coroutines to handle request in background thread.

We want to test above method by using unit test. I don't know what is the right way to test my method. But the requirement is to test this method from unit test class. We want to test this method on android & iOS. As per the above code I have created asynchronous request. But I want to test it as synchronously. As per the research I tried two ways.

1. **By using androidInstrumentedTest module inside commonMain**

   I have inherited the TestCase class in my unit test class. Using this I can override **setUp()** method. setUp() method calls initially.

   ```
   override fun setUp() {

           val expectation = CountDownLatch(1)
           consumerCloud.testApi(
           success = {
               expectation.countDown()
                     },

           failure = {
               fail(it.toString())
               expectation.countDown()

           })
           expectation.await()

           super.setUp()
       }
   ```

   Am using **CountDownLatch** class to make my asynchronous request as synchronous. expectation.await() wait for the block execution. But in this case am getting an error:

   **android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)**
2. **By using commonTest module inside commonMain**

   I have inherited the TestCase class in my unit test. Using this I can override **setUp()** method. setUp() method calls initially. In this case We don't have access to use android/iOS specific class. So we are not able to use CountDownLatch class to make our request as synchronous. So I tried with **runBocking { }**. Even I have also tried with runTest { } because runBlockingTest is deprecated.

   ```
   override fun setUp() {
       runBlocking {
           consumerCloud.testApi(
               success = {
                   println("success")
               },

               failure = {
                   println("error")
                   fail(it.toString())

               }) 
       }

       super.setUp()
   }
   ```

   In this case testApi() method called but it runs independently. Test case passed but it doesn't wait for the api execution.

If I call testApi() method from androidMain module or commonMain module then api executed successfully with asynchronous behaviour. There is no network related issues . Because I have added required permissions in Manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Please help me to perform unit testing for both platforms.

I want to perform network calls unit testing for android/iOS platforms

Comment: Dont make network calls in unit tests. Mock the results you expect and test against those.

Comment: I can't make mock results because I'm creating multiplatform plugin. So other developer can just call the method and get the desired output. The requirement to perform realtime testing with actual request & response. So I can't mock the resullts.

Comment: And I have created network calls in shared module. Am just calling that method from unit tests.

Comment: Your *shared* logic layer should handle the data request and pass just whats needed for the various implementations to display on the UI layer.

Comment: As I have mentioned, am just making a plugin for different platforms, plugin will be used by other developer to call these methods. But before integration i want to be sure about my functionality that's why am writing unit tests